# Debug setup for an ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rider

**Edit: After downgrading to .NET SDK 1.0.4, I can debug my app inside Rider and experience is pretty good.**

What is the best way to set up a clean debug configuration for my ASP.NET Core app on Ubuntu in Rider 2017.1?

I want to just click on Debug button and have the tool automatically build the app, host it on some port, and open the url in browser.

Should I just try to use `launchSettings.json`(as VS automatically creates) or Rider offers something else?

I have .NET Command Line Tools `2.0.0-preview2-006497` installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Until a new version of Rider with .Net Core support is released, debugging doesn't work.

In fact, you'll see the event log full of messages like this if you try:

> 12:01 PM  .NET Core version problem: .NET Core 2.x is not fully supported. Some features will not work as expected.

(You can still just open a project and hit the play button and it'll run your project; but hitting the debug button doesn't actually work at the moment)

As of the time of writing, testing, nuget restore, project references (ie. between projects in the same solution) and running in debug don't work.

For now it's just a waiting game until the next version of rider comes out with these features [in Fall, 2017](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/08/03/rider-2017-1-jetbrains-net-ide-hits-rtm/#what's%20next):

> We want to roll out at least two more releases this year: an inevitable bugfix release in a few weeks, and another major release (2017.2) in the Fall. Things that we expect to be addressing include support for **MSTest and .NET Core 2.0**, as well as releasing an SDK. We’ll certainly be keeping a close eye on your feedback (submitted via the support form, issue tracker or elsewhere) to see what other major issues need to be addressed.

Comment: I downgraded netcore sdk to 1.0.4 and am happy to see Rider does support debugging too